# Is this css code incorrect?

Tags: css

Please note I am somewhat vision impaired and find it hard sometimes to   between: and ;when it's on plain paper. Can anyone please help and  let me know where this code is incorrect?

```
auto!imports;}
.section_title {margin-bottom:35px;}
.bottom_wrapper {padding:0;}
.gbtr_footer_widget_credit_cards_img
{display hidden!important;}
.entry-title {display:none;}
.entry-meta {display:none;}
WooZone-price-info {display:none;}
```

Thanks jay28

Comment: You should use a tool like [csslint](http://csslint.net)

Answer (score 1):

```
auto!imports;}
```

I've never used or seen a CSS code starting with a line similar to this. It seems to me as if this is some part in the middle of a bigger code. Whether it's acceptable or not, it won't affect the rest of the style code.

And also, this line wouldn't make any effect :

```
WooZone-price-info {display:none;}
```

Maybe you have missed something there. It should either be

```
.WooZone-price-info {display:none;}
```

or

```
#WooZone-price-info {display:none;}
```

The rest of the code is fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
auto!imports;} /* erase this line if it is not part of other stuff.*/
.section_title {margin-bottom:35px;}
.bottom_wrapper {padding:0;}
.gbtr_footer_widget_credit_cards_img
{display hidden!important;} /* add colon (:) sign after disply*/
.entry-title {display:none;}
.entry-meta {display:none;}
WooZone-price-info {display:none;} /* add dot(.) or hash(#) sign before WooZone-price-info because it is not a Tag */
```

**thus final css like this:**

```
.section_title {margin-bottom:35px;}
.bottom_wrapper {padding:0;}
.gbtr_footer_widget_credit_cards_img{display: hidden!important;}
.entry-title {display:none;}
.entry-meta {display:none;}
.WooZone-price-info {display:none;}
```

**Or**

```
.section_title {margin-bottom:35px;}
.bottom_wrapper {padding:0;}
.gbtr_footer_widget_credit_cards_img{display: hidden!important;}
.entry-title {display:none;}
.entry-meta {display:none;}
#WooZone-price-info {display:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you don't have any tag called `<WooZone-price-info>`

But your last declaration says:

```
WooZone-price-info {display:none;}
```

Maybe you mean:

```
#WooZone-price-info {display:none;}
```

or

```
.WooZone-price-info {display:none;}
```

Also the first line is complete nonsense, did you copy only half of the code?

Comment: https://www.parhamdoustdar.com/2016/04/03/tools-of-blind-programmer/ talks about IDE's for the visually impaired, perhaps you might find that useful, certainly a good IDE with auto-complete would help.